# Injecting one ejb bean inside another within the same jar module not working

Tags: jboss, ejb, cdi, weld

I have two beans in my jar module -> 
bean A:

```
@Singleton
public final class A {
    public String getS() {
        return"";
}
```

and a second bean B within the same jar module:

```
@Stateless
public final class B {
    @Inject
    private A a;

    public String getAS() {
        a.getS() // -> NullPointerException
    }
}
```

I have the file **beans.xml** in

```
src/main/resources/META-INF/
```

```
<groupId>javaee</groupId>
<artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
<scope>provided</scope>
```

is added to pom.xml, but still injected A is null.

**In a generated jar file beans.xml is present**

whether I missed something?

Comment: Do you see the beans.xml finally in the jar?

Comment: @Laertes Indeed I don't really see beans.xml in my jar file, hymm what that might be cause?

Comment: @Kukeltje javaee api is provided and class B is stateless ejb bean

Comment: @Kukeltje I wrote about javaee dependency and what difference does it make whether B is stateless or POJO should be injectable

Comment: ok I added this details

Comment: And how do you know injection is not working? I don't see any code where the injected bean is used that e.g. throws an NPE due to the injection not working. And does 'injection' work if you change `@Inject` to `@EJB`?

Comment: I removed my now superfluous comments.

Comment: Yes it's throw NullPointerException and I can also see it in debug mode. change on @EJB throw CreationException -> NameNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

The default place for the beans.xml for building jars with maven would be in

```
src/main/resources/META-INF/
```

Comment: That's where I have the beans.xml

Comment: If the path is src\main\resources\META-INF\beans.xml Maven puts it automatically in the rigth place in the jar. You might double check it...